# not a valid UUID , how to catch wrong UUID?

Tags: python, django, uuid

I am having a validation error when I set a random string in my url as token. How can i catch this validation error?

For example:
when accesing: https://www.example.com/stream/8e258b27-c787-49ef-9539-11461b251ffad

The error is `ValidationError at /stream/8e258b27-c787-49ef-9539-11461b251ffad ['“8e258b27-c787-49ef-9539-11461b251ffad” is not a valid UUID.']`

my code is this:

```
def stream(request, token):
user = Creador.objects.filter(stream_token=token).first()
if user:
    return render(request, 'app1/stream.html', {
        'token':token, 'user':user
    })
else:
    return HttpResponse("Token no existe")
```

any ideas? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if a string is a valid v4 UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989481/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-valid-v4-uuid)

Comment: @iklinac unluckily it doesnt :(

Comment: what exactly is unclear to you,  in your provided code you do not set anything also your random string is not valid UUID. Please do provide  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example